# Ruby on Rails - Underline words if they appear in dynamically generated text using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to underline words that are dynamically generated by the debug(params) method provided by rails. I have something below, but it obviously does not work, plus what I have below is attempt to try and change the words using methods that I already know about (like the .upcase method). I was hoping to underline the word controller if it appears in the text using only Ruby. Can anyone help me out here?

```
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    <% if debug(params).include?('controller:') %>
      <%= 'controller'.upcase %>
    <% end %>
```

thanks

edit:

I should add that debug(params) is a method defined by RAILS, I was able to do the following which seems even more off, so far the answers have not been correct to what I want to do.

```
  <% if Rails.env.development? %>
    <% debug_method = debug(params).split.each do |word|  %>
      <% if word  == 'controller:' %>
        <ul><% word.upcase %></ul>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
    <%= debug_method.join %>
  <% end %>
```

which returns the following text: https://ibb.co/cvnEpw , keep the answers coming in though. I want to get the words in the original box (that's generated by the method to underline the controller word https://ibb.co/jmSm2G).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is below. I had to use the .gsub and .html_safe methods.

```
  <%= debug(params).gsub("controller:", "<u>controller:</u>").html_safe %>
```

This code keeps the existing html & css generated by rails intact

Answer (score 0):

use `<u></u>`  tag

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    <% if debug(params).include?('controller:') %>
    <u><%= 'controller'.upcase %></u>
<% end %>
```

[example here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp)

Comment: https://imgur.com/RBUMs9V      https://ibb.co/ezOZNG That is a step close, but still not what I'm looking for. I want the words in the box to be underlined.

Comment: no errors, i made an edit in the original post if you care to read it

Answer (score 0):

Provide the css to generate html element:

```
p { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Add html elemnt to wrap your words:

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    <% if debug(params).include?('controller:') %>
    <p> <%= 'controller'.upcase %> </p>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: not quite what im looking for, I made an edit in the original post if u care to read it